# Solving a^(b^c) using fermats little theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

How do I go about finding the solution to the following equation:

$a^{(b^c)} \equiv x \;(\bmod\; n)$

(assume $n$ does not divide $a$ for the purposes of using fermats little theorem)

Assume a and b can be somewhat small values around 5 to 100 and c can take values 1,000 to 10,000. What is the general algorithm for solving for $x$ using pen and paper?

I find this question pretty confusing because of the 3 exponents. I can solve regular problems of the type $a^{b} \equiv x \;(\bmod\; n)$ but I must be missing something with this one.

Example problems:

$2^{(6^{2015})} \equiv x \;(\bmod\; 19)$ - find $x$

$2^{(6^{2015})} \equiv y \;(\bmod\; 23)$ - find $y$ - really need help with this one

Comment: You already have isolated $x$ and $y$ terms, aren't you?

Comment: @Bumblebee Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: So, $2^{n}\equiv x\pmod{19}$ will depend on what the exponent $n$ happens to be mod $19-1$ (*even in the case that $n$ happens to be of the form $b^c$*).  So to simplify $2^{6^{2015}}\pmod{19}$ you'll want to first simplify $6^{2015}\pmod{18}$.  For that, it helps to notice that $6\cdot 6 = 2\cdot 18$.  It is just going to be repeated applications of fermats and/or chinese remainder or other similar techniques.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay, so $6^2 = 36 = 2*18$ then we get that $2^{2*18*6^{2013}} = 2^{{(2*18)}^{6^{2013}}} = 2^{{18}^{{2}^{{6}^{2013}}}}$ but we know that 2^{18} is congruent to 1 so we just get 1 as the answer? Can you confirm if my steps here are correct?

Comment: Once you add appropriate parentheses remembering that $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}\neq (a^b)^c$, yes the result of the first will indeed be $1$.  The second is done similarly except notice that $6$ has $2$ as a factor but does not have $11$ as a factor, affecting how we look at $6^n\pmod{22}$.  You'll want to look at the two problems of $6^n\pmod{2}$ and $6^n\pmod{11}$ separately.

Comment: You mean to write $2^{2\cdot 18\cdot 6^{2013}} = ((2^{18})^2)^{(6^{2013})}$  (*only the parentheses around $6^{2013}$ can be omitted here*).  What you wrote parses as $2^{{18}^{{2}^{{6}^{2013}}}}=2^{(18^{(2^{(6^{2013})})})}$ which is not what you intended.

Comment: ah I see, had a little trouble with putting that into math code with 4 exponents in a row... yes that would be correct. I still have a little trouble  getting the second example problem down. Not sure how to tackle it with the two factors... The first one was difficult enough as it was for me getting the exponents correct. Is this correct then?

$ 2^{2*18*6^{2013}} = (2^{{2*18})^(6^{2013})} = ((2^{18})^{2})^{(6^{2013})} $

Comment: "I'm not sure how to tackle it with the two factors"  Have you heard of the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: I'm afraid not.. but from what I'm hearing it seems very useful so I'll try to study up on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$23$ is prime so $2^{22} \equiv 1 \mod 23$

So $2^{6^{2015}} \equiv 2^k \mod 23$ where $6^{2015} \equiv k \mod 22$ so we must solve $6^{2015}\equiv k \mod 22$.

Use Chinese remainder theorem.  $22 = 2*11$

$6^{2015} \equiv 6^5 \mod 11$ so $6^5 = 36*36*6\equiv 3*3*6 \equiv 54 \equiv -1 \mod 11$ and $6^{2015} \equiv 0 \mod 2$.

So $6^{2015} \equiv 10 \mod 22$.

So $2^{6^{2015}} \equiv 2^{10} \equiv 1024\equiv 12  \mod 23$.

====

> I'm not familiar with the Chinese Remainder theorem, does it mean that I can simply split it into two separate questions of the two factors 2 and 11, do I just add the results then? And also.. how do I get the first part where you switch to mod 22 to solve for k?

Okay,  Details.

By FLT $2^{22} \equiv 1 \mod 23$

So if $6^{2015} = 22m + r$ then $2^{5^{2015}}\equiv 2^{22m + r} \equiv (2^{22})^m*2^k \equiv 1*2^k \equiv 2^r \mod 23$.

So we must solve $6^{2015} = 22m + r$ or in other words we must solve $6^{2015} \equiv r \mod 22$.

Question 1: What is $6^{2015} \equiv r \mod 22$.

Now we can't use FLT because $6$ and $22$ are not relatively prime.

But we can use the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) that says.

If $n,m$ are relatively prime and if $x \equiv a \mod n$ and $x \equiv b \mod m$ then there is a unique solution to $x \mod nm$.

So $22 = 2*11$ and $\gcd (2,11) = 1$.

So if $x \equiv 6^{2015}\equiv 0 \mod 2$

and $x \equiv 6^{2015} \equiv (6^{10})^{201}*6^5 \equiv 6^5\equiv 10 \mod 11$

Then there will be a unique solution $6^{2015}\equiv x \mod 22$.

Now $0 \equiv 10 \mod 2$ and $10 \equiv 10 \mod 11$.  And $10 \equiv 10 \mod 22$. so $x \equiv 10 \mod 22$ is *a* solution to $x\equiv 0 \mod 10$ and $x\equiv 10 \mod 11$.   And by the chinese remainder theorem it is a *unique* solution.

So $6^{2015}\equiv 10 \mod 22$.

So $6^{2015} = 22m + 10$.

So $2^{6^{2015}} = 2^{22m + 10} \equiv (2^{22})^{m}*2^{10} \equiv 2^{10}\equiv 1024\equiv 12 \mod 23$.

=====

Okay,  *without* CRT.  We still need to find $6^{2015} \mod 22$.

$6^2 = 36 \equiv 14\equiv -8\mod 22$

$6^3 \equiv -8*6 \equiv -48 = -4 \mod 22$.

$6^4 \equiv -24 \equiv -2 \mod 22$

$6^5 \equiv -12 \equiv 10 \mod 22$

$6^6 \equiv 60 \equiv -6 \mod 22$

So $6^{2015} \equiv 6^{6*335+5}\equiv (-6)^{335}*6^{5}$

$\equiv (-6)^{6* 55+ 5}*10$

$\equiv (-6)^{55}*(-10)*10$

$ \equiv (-6)^{6*9 + 1}*(-100)$

$\equiv (-6)^9*(600)$

$\equiv (-6)^{6+3}* 6$

$\equiv (-6)*(-6)^3*6$

$\equiv 6^5 \equiv 10 \mod 22$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Chinese Remainder theorem, does it mean that I can simply split it into two separate questions of the two factors 2 and 11, do I just add the results then? And also.. how do I get the first part where you switch to mod 22 to solve for k?

Comment: If you are not familiar with the CRT you will have to study.  No, you can not add the results.  But if $\gcd(n,m) = 1$ and $x \equiv k \mod n$ and $x \equiv j \mod m$ the chinese remainder th. will say there is a *unique* solution to $x \mod nm$.  As $10\equiv 0 \mod 2$ and $10 \equiv -1 \mod 11$ and $10 \equiv 10 \mod 22$ I know that if $x \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and $x \equiv -1 \mod 11$ that there has to be a unique solution $mod 22$ and as $10$ is a solution... that is it.

Comment: I see, thanks. Well we did not learn CRT in our class so I assume we are supposed to do it without it. I'll look into and learn it as it's been mentioned a few times but are you sure it's not possible without using CRT?

Comment: @fleabood Hey thanks I aced my finals thanks to you.